# Is the prime factorisation of Carmichael Numbers always Square Free?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is the prime factorisation of carmichael Numbers always square free?

I saw the next theorem in my textbook which would say yes.

[image]

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Korselt's_criterion

Comment: Please do not use pictures!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a prime factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p^2 \mid n$.
Let $t$ be a primitive root modulo $p^2$, thus, $p \mid o_{p^2}(t)$.
And hence, $p^2 \nmid t^{n}-t \iff p^2 \nmid t^{n-1}-1 $. Latter one being true by our choice of $t$.